# RSS Feed Designer - Control field types?

Tags: rss

When using the Feed Designer, Sitecore appears to be pulling `Single Line Text` and `Multi Line Text` fields.

Can this be updated to also include custom field types? (e.g., we have a type `Raw Text`) Maybe a pipeline or configuration?

Comment: `Raw Text` is a custom field, or do you mean the deprecated `text` field type?

Comment: `Raw Text` is indeed a custom field type that we've created.

Comment: https://sitecorejunkie.com/2014/11/03/add-additional-item-fields-to-rss-feeds-generated-by-sitecore/ this will get you what you need. Sitecore uses the .Net Syndication item. You will have access to the entire Item if you follow along that post. Read your custom field however you need to. I’ve used it before to make customizations. It’s pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

Once you use the designer, you will see this appear in your shared layout of your standard values:

```
<d id="{73966209-F1B6-43CA-853A-F1DB1C9A654B}" l="{A57C19C2-8EE3-4DEC-AA39-0B8D522D59EB}">
   <r id="{86F838F5-7E87-45BB-876F-C021324AC8B0}" par="TitleField=Field+1&amp;BodyField=Field+2&amp;DateField=Field+3" uid="{11865658-1F3C-415F-975D-67F6BD76EEBA}" />
</d>
```

You can simply swap out `Field+1` as necessary.  It will work at render time of the RSS Feed, but the designer will show an empty value for the title field.